# SQLite.swift sets all fields to NOT NULL

Tags: sqlite.swift

Version 11.4

All of my Sqlite table fields are set to NOT NULL.

I have tried the following in the table creation command ..

```
t.column(miny, defaultValue: nil)
```

but the fields are still all defined 'NOT NULL'

How do I set a field to accept a NULL value?

Answer (score 1):

Doh! - found the answer looking through the testing scripts in github - then noticed the comment in the docs.

Need to make the types optional using a '?' - as with the last 4 Double fields in this example ..

```
    let title = Expression<String>("title")
    let descr = Expression<String>("descr")
    let miny = Expression<Double?>("miny") 
    let minx = Expression<Double?>("minx")
    let maxy = Expression<Double?>("maxy")
    let maxx = Expression<Double?>("maxx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following syntax:

```
t.column(miny)
```

From the SQLite [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

> The default value of each column is NULL

So you should not have to specify anything extra in a column definition in order for it to be nullable, because the default value is already null.